# Best approach to remove cassandra-topology.properties file in running cluster nodes

Tags: cassandra, nosql

There is 3 node cassandra cluster running and which is serving Production Traffic And in cassandra.yaml file "`endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch`" is configured but somehow we have forgot to remove file `cassandra-topology.properties` from cassandra conf directory. As per Cassandra documentation if you are using `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` you should remove `cassandra-topology.properties` file.

Now As all three nodes are running and serving Production traffic So can I remove this file all three nodes or I have to remove this file  after shutdown the nodes one by one.

Apache Cassandra Version is "3.11.2"

```
./bin/nodetool status
Datacenter: dc1
================
Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                       Rack
UN  x.x.x.x1     409.39 GiB   256          62.9%         cshdkd-6065-4813-ae53-sdh89hs98so  RAC1
UN  x.x.x.x2     546.33 GiB   256          67.8%         jfdsdk-f18f-4d46-af95-33jw9yhfcsd  RAC2
UN  x.x.x.x3     594.73 GiB   256          69.3%         7s9skk-a27f-4875-a410-sdsiudw9eww  RAC3
```

Answer (score 3):

If the cluster is already migrated to GossippingPropertyFileSnitch, then you can safely remove that file without stopping the cluster nodes. See the [item 7 in DSE 5.1 documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsSwitchSnitch.html) (compatible with Cassandra 3.11)

Comment: Thanks Alex for answer..!!